# How to create a total new connetion to Mysql in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, dbcontext

Inside a store procedure, I create a temporary table to store the result,I know  so It will be conflicted if there are **more than 1 call** to this store procedure **in 1 connection** (because it use just 1 temp table name => there are no distinguish to know which one belong to which request).

```
BEGIN
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TempTable (RowOrdinal INT DEFAULT 0);
  INSERT INTO TempTable(RowOrdinal) VALUES (1);
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TempTable;
END $$
```

As you can see, in the same connection, each time you call this store, TempTable will be added 1 more row.

In my C# project, I test a few ways to make a new MySQL connection to call the store procedure.

1. Create new dbcontext (in entity framework), then using

   ```
   public int CallStoreFunction()
   {
      return result = dbcontext.Database.SqlQuery<int>("CALL store_proc()");
   }
   ```
2. Create connection by making a new instance:

   ```
   public int CallStoreFunction()
   {
     var result = 0;
     using(var connection  = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
       connection.Open();
       var command = new MySqlCommand("CALL store_proc()", connection) 
       result =  int.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
       connection.Close();
     }
     return result;
   }
   ```

With each way, I call this function four times and the result after all is 4 (which mean each call to the store is still in the same connection)

Look like C# just creates a new session/ transaction, not a  new connection, no matter in which approach I used. What I wonder is it a way to create a total different connection to DB in each time I make a request to this store?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you create your temporary table, you are using the [`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-temporary-table.html) syntax, right? Both EF and ADO use connection pooling, so you'll often be returned the same connection from the pool, if the connection has been released (which you are doing with the Close + Dispose). `TEMPORARY` Tables should be per session, so even with connection pooling, they should be unique.

Answer (score 2):

The ADO.NET manage connections in Connection Pool. When you call **Open** a connection, it will look for an available connection in the pool. If it's available, it will be returned (do not create a new connection). And when you call **Close**, it will be returned to the pool with active status (it is ready to be reused).

Therefore, your codes are still using the same connection and the same temporary table. If you want to create a totally connection, you should **Clearing the Pool** first. The ADO.NET supports ClearAllPools and ClearPool, for MySQL it looks like:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.ClearPool(connection);
```

**For example:**

```
        var result = 0;

        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["your_connection"].ConnectionString;
        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var command = new MySqlCommand("CALL new_procedure()", connection);
            result = int.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.ClearPool(connection);
            connection.Close();                 
        }

        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var command = new MySqlCommand("CALL new_procedure()", connection);
            result = int.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            connection.Close();                
        }
        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var command = new MySqlCommand("CALL new_procedure()", connection);
            result = int.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            connection.Close();                
        }
```

**result = 1, and result = 2**

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling